# In which cases is it necessary to use MTLStoreActionStoreAndMultisampleResolve instead of MTLStoreActionMultisampleResolve?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, metal, metalkit

With `MTLStoreActionStoreAndMultisampleResolve`, the multisample values are stored in the attachment and also resolved into single-sample values that are stored in the texture specified by the `resolveTexture` property. But in which cases is it useful to store the multisample values in the attachment? As far as I know there is no load action for the multisample texture (or I missed something). I also don't really know in which way this multisample texture is used.

Answer (score 0):

This store action can be used when you want to resolve an MSAA render target in the ordinary way, and also preserve its contents for further operations.

One example of such an operation would be a custom MSAA resolve filter. Metal allows you to bind a multisample texture as a shader function argument, provided its `access` attribute is `read` (meaning you can't write or sample a multisample texture). The Metal Shading Language (MSL) includes functions for specifying a coordinate and sample index to read from:

```
Tv read(uint2 coord, uint sample) const
```

The `get_num_samples()` function is available determine the sample count of a multisampled texture.

If you have customized sample positions (set with the `setSamplePositions:count:` method of `MTLRenderPassDescriptor`), the free function `get_sample_position(uint index)` returns the position for the specified index.

These shader functions can be used together to manually resolve an MSAA texture with a shader. You can imagine that certain applications could benefit from using a custom set of sample positions and combining the samples in a way that differs from the ordinary technique of taking the average.